# schema for complex data type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have json data like below:

```
{"ModelId":"m1","AddCompleted":[{"UniqueId":"c1"}, {"UniqueId":"c2"}],"AddActive":[{"UniqueId":"a1"}],"AddPlanned":[{"UniqueId":"p1"}]}
```

do i have to use nested/sub-schema like below:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ModelId: { type: string, unique: true, required: true },
    AddCompleted: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: string }), { _id: false } ],
    AddActive: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: string }), { _id: false } ],
    AddPlanned: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: string }, { _id: false }) ],
});
```

or can simply use:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ModelId: { type: string, unique: true, required: true },
    AddCompleted: [ { type: string } ],
    AddActive: [ { type: string } ],
    AddPlanned: [ { type: string } ],
});
```

Comment: `{"UniqueId":"c1"}` is an _object_ (not a _string_).

Comment: right, so which one should i use

Comment: const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ModelId: { type: string, unique: true, required: true },
    AddCompleted: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: { type: string }, { _id: false }}) ],
    AddActive: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: { type: string }, { _id: false }}) ],
    AddPlanned: [ new Schema({ UniqueId: { type: string }, { _id: false }}) ],
});

Comment: const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ModelId: { type: string, unique: true, required: true },
    AddCompleted: [ { UniqueId: { type: string }} ],
    AddActive: [ { UniqueId: { type: string }} ],
    AddPlanned: [ { UniqueId: { type: string }} ],
});

Comment: i assume 1st option w/ nested schema is correct one

Comment: You can try it and see if it works.

Comment: works OK w/ mongoose, thanks